# ZAPIER output_missing Please define output or return early

Tags: zapier

I am trying to get a document from a form here, but my script out is missing. Am i doing anything wrong here. This seems to work when there is more than on argument but it is just one it seems not to be working

```py
try:
    documents = {}
    if "Select which supporting documentation you would like to accompany your motivation letter" in input_data['checkbox']:
        documents['doc1']="https://essentialmedicalguidance.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/brand/Eli+Lilly/Trulicity/VAE_Trulicity+Package+Insert.pdf"
        return documents
except:
    return {'empty' : True}
```

Answer (score 1):

The function always has to return (or set) data. In the case where `'Select which...'` is not in `input_data['checkbox']`, then nothing is returned.

Try something like this instead, which will be more consistent (if you add more fields):

```py
result = {}
if 'Select which...' in input_data['checkbox']:
    result['doc1'] = 'https://ess...'

return result
```

This way, your output is still conditional, but *something* is always returned.